# Loop but output which line is being referenced

Tags: bash, loops, variables, while-loop

I have script that I wrote to loop through email accounts and output if the account have anyone assigned sendAs permissions.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
     zmprov -l ga "$line" | grep zimbraACE >> accountsout.txt

done < accounts.txt
```

The script works but the out but the output doesn't help me determine which accounts each entry or set of entries belongs to.

```
zimbraACE: 12bf9714-9c6d-46ce-b15d-c127bfffae usr viewFreeBusy
zimbraACE: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000 all viewFreeBusy
zimbraACE: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000 all viewFreeBusy
zimbraACE: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000 all -viewFreeBusy
zimbraACE: 538c5495-8e50-43cb-9131-e893695bd5 usr sendAs
zimbraACE: 23beb905-67c0-4e0d-9e85-405de5babd usr sendAs
```

I am hoping to have it output the line reference before the attributes a la:

```
zimbrasucks@imbra.org
zimbraACE: 12bf9714-9c6d-46ce-b15d-c127bfffae usr viewFreeBusy
zimbraACE: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000 all viewFreeBusy
zimbraACE: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000 all viewFreeBusy
zimbraACE: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000 all -viewFreeBusy
dontusethisproduct@zimbra.org
zimbraACE: 538c5495-8e50-43cb-9131-e893695bd5 usr sendAs
zimbraACE: 23beb905-67c0-4e0d-9e85-405de5babd usr sendAs
```

I know I have to catch the output of each iteration as second varible and then output both variables per loop but I'm not even sure where to start in bash.

Comment: So add `echo "$line" >> accountsout.txt` ???

Answer (score 1):

Save the `grep` output in a variable. Then check whether `grep` was successful, and print the email before printing the variable.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    temp=$(zmprov -l ga "$line" | grep zimbraACE)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "$line"
        echo "$temp"
    fi
done < accounts.txt > accountsout.txt
```

Comment: Looks great, Thank you!

Comment: You can check the exit status of the command substitution by using the assignment as the condition: `if temp=$(zmprov -l ga "$line" | grep zimbraACE); then`